# How to get String inside object Gson/Retrofit2

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm making a response to this Google Books API [URL](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android)

I have an Retrofit request:'

```
public interface BookApiService {

    @GET("/books/v1/volumes")
    Call<Books> getBooks(@Query("q") String query);
}
```

And have an Entity classes

**Books.java**

```
public class Books {

    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<Book> items;

    public List<Book> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

and **Book.java**

```
public class Book {

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String mTitle;
    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }
}
```

Request is working correct, i mean no errors with connection, and retrofit returns onResponse, not onFailure.
But my String "title" is null. How can i get this. Please check JSON response by link above.

**UPDATE**:

Retrofit call:

```
public class BookService{

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/";
    private BookApiService mApiService;
    private BookCallback mListener;

    public BookService(BookCallback listener){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build();

        mApiService = retrofit.create(BookApiService.class);

        mListener = listener;
    }



    public void getBooks(String query){
        Call<Books> call = mApiService.getBooks(query);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Books>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Books> call, Response<Books> response) {
                mListener.notifyDataReceived(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Books> call, Throwable t) {

                mListener.notifyErrorReceived(t);
            }
        });
    }

    public interface BookCallback{
        void notifyDataReceived(Books books);
        void notifyErrorReceived(Throwable error);
    }
```

BookCallback listener is my **MainActivity**: 
When i check Logs, there is

> "SUCCESS" "TITLE 1 null"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    new BookService(this).getBooks("android");

}

@Override
public void notifyDataReceived(Books books) {
    if(books.getItems() != null) {
        List<Book> items = books.getItems();
        Log.d(TAG, "Success");
        Log.d(TAG, "TITLE 1" + items.get(0).getTitle());
        setupAdapter(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post here your retrofit call.

Comment: @Kabir Check please, updated!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]. In particular, how do you call `getBooks()`? What is the value of `query`? Also, I suggest using a tool such as Postman to make the request manually to see what it returns.

Comment: Try this :Log.d(TAG, "TITLE 1" + items.get(0).getVolumeInfo().getTitle());

Comment: @Kabir What is `getVolumeInfo()`? I don't see that method in the OPs code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice volumeInfo object mention in api response...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added my `getBooks()` call, check please

Comment: @Kabir Yes, i need `"title"` inside `volumeInfo`, but cannot get it

Comment: @Rarity7- Make your model class from :http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: @Kabir Then the OP needs to add `getVolumeInfo()` method to his `Book` class. I suggest you write up a complete explanation that includes all of the parts that the OP is missing.

Comment: @Rarity7- It looks like your entity classes don't quite match the shape of the response from the API. You can use a tool like Postman or curl to inspect the response payload. From there you can make modifications to your `Books`, `Book`, etc. classes to accurately represent the data.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice As you can see in JSON response, there is an Object which i convert to `Books.class`, inside this Object i have an Array `items`, which i convert to `List<Book>`, and inside this Array, there is another Object `volumeInfo`, with `title` which i need

Comment: @Rarity7- Yes, I see what you are talking about, now. However, changing `items.get(0).getTitle()` to `items.get(0).getVolumeInfo().getTitle()` will cause a compiler error because `Book` doesn't have a method named `getVolumeInfo()`. You have clearly identified the problem, but to completely fix it, there are other changes required. If you write out the details as an answer, I'm sure the OP will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request the JSON directly in your browser [here](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android). Looking closely at this data, you will see that `items[0]` doesn't have a property `title`. Instead, there is a property `volumeInfo` that contains `title`. Your Retrofit entity class needs to correctly navigate to that property in order to get the data you need.

Comment: Yes i got it, but how can i fix it. Need i change `@SerializeName("title")` to `@SerializeName("volumeInfo/title")`? Or it will no work. Or i need to create Object `VolumeInfo`, which include `@Serialized("title")`?

Comment: @Rarity7- I'm very new to Retrofit, so I don't know the exact details. Your second solution will most likely work, but requires more code for a new class. Your first solution seems much more ideal since it is a smaller change. Since JavaScript and JSON use a `.` to reference properties, I would first try `@SerializeName("volumeInfo.title")`.